# Source Tree - install behind proxy

Tags: git, proxy, atlassian-sourcetree

I am not able to install source tree behind proxy in work.

I was looking for all kind of versions but there is no answer and when i found some and install it, it wont allow me to run program.

Is it possible to install it on Windows like that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.
You simply need to create a license file in order to skip the need to connect to the internet and login to your attlassian account.

Place the file under your account in the following location:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\accounts.json

[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "SourceTree.Api.Host.Identity.Model.IdentityAccount, SourceTree.Api.Host.Identity",
    "Authenticate": true,
    "HostInstance": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "SourceTree.Host.Atlassianaccount.AtlassianAccountInstance, SourceTree.Host.AtlassianAccount",
      "Host": {
        "$id": "3",
        "$type": "SourceTree.Host.Atlassianaccount.AtlassianAccountHost, SourceTree.Host.AtlassianAccount",
        "Id": "atlassian account"
      },
      "BaseUrl": "https://id.atlassian.com/"
    },
    "Credentials": {
      "$id": "4",
      "$type": "SourceTree.Model.BasicAuthCredentials, SourceTree.Api.Account",
      "Username": "",
      "Email": null
    },
    "IsDefault": false
  }
]
```